# The size of QPushButton breaks layout height (MacOS)

Tags: macos, qt

Lets consider situation with QFormLayout. For example need to add button to the layout row:

[image: form]

As you see the height of layout with button is bigger than height of other rows. This is because the own height of the button is bigger than height of the line editor – there is empty space around the button:

[image: button size]

In result all layouts with QPushButton becomes broken. Even in standard dialogs (QMessageBox) there are big margins around buttons in the bottom of the window.

As I know this issue is relevant only for MacOs.
There are some similar issues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18612370/qpushbutton-creates-empty-space-on-mac-os-x-resulting-in-ugly-layouts) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12327609/qpushbutton-changes-margins-on-other-widgets-in-the-same-layout?s=6%7C0.9612), but there is no answer why QPushButton on Mac has such size, and how to fix this properly.

Comment: It is a problem with minimum size hint.

Answer (score 0):

IMO this is problem with margins. With different style (used on OSX) margin is altered and you have this effect.

Try tweak this by setting a style sheet:

```
pushButton->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
                          "    margin: 2px;\n"
                          "}\n")
```

Comment: this is bad solution because the button loses its shape - becomes square.